# Is Firefox going to support h264 tag on ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

Firefox will soon support the video tag h264 on Windows. Will there be a solution on Ubuntu?

Comment: Where did you here this?

Answer (score 2):

When compiled with multimedia support, Firefox already does support H.264 (as I have seen on both Gentoo and FreeBSD) For this kind of support to arrive on Ubuntu would mean that one has to make it so that Firefox would install this support when installing the .deb file (by default, it is turned off)

So to answer your question: support may come sooner than you think! (There just has to be high enough demand for a .deb file with support already enabled in it)